# Django MRSS add item into item - using syndication feed framework

Tags: python, django, syndication-feed, django-syndication

I'm using the [syndication feed framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/syndication/) to generate an MRSS feed.
I was able to add a custom filed media:group inside the item element.

I'm looking how I can add media:content element inside media:group, here is the sample I would like to generate:

```
<item>
    <media:group>
        <media:content> 1 </media:content>
        <media:content> 2 </media:content>
    </media:group>
</item>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
handler.startElement("media:group", {})
handler.addQuickElement(u"media:content", 'your content', media_dict_attrs)
handler.endElement("media:group")
```